# How to read a return value from another function in another javascript file

Tags: javascript, return-value, testcomplete

I need to read return value from a function from another javascript file. I am using Test Complete as tool with Javascript

Javascriptfile1

```
function myFunction1()
    {
    // Marks need to display from myFunction2
}
```

Javascriptfile2

```
function myFunction2()
    {
     var marks= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Javascriptfile1`

```
export default function myFunction1()
{
    return 10
}
```

In `Javascriptfile2`

```
import myFunction1 from './Javascriptfile1'

function myFunction2()
{
     var marks = myFunction1()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this..

Function 1:

```
 function sample1(stringVal)
 {
   return stringVal;
 }
```

Function 2: (Another file)

```
var returnResult = sample1("SampleString");
```